# Additivity and linear combination of chi-squared distributed variables

Tags: variance, degrees-of-freedom, chi-squared-distribution, pooling

I am trying to get a better understanding of the Satterthwaite pooled degrees of freedom estimation, which led to understanding the general problem of pooling variances. My confusion, in short, is related to the addititivity of $\chi^2$ random variables vs. linear combinations of $\chi^2$ random variables.

The additivity property of the $\chi^2$ distribution says that the sum of multiple $\chi^2$ random variables is distributed $\chi^2$ with degrees of freedom equal to the sum of the individual degrees of freedoms. However, when combining multiple variances (e.g the Behrens-Fisher problem, or quasi-F statistics) even when you are merely summing two independent $\chi^2$ variables (e.g. two variances), you cannot treat the resulting variable as distributed $\chi^2$.

After more reading and thinking since I first asked this question, is the problem that the variances you are summing are independent but not from *identical* distributions? Most definitions of additivity I found only mention independence and don't say the observations need to be sampled from identical normal distributions. If not, why can you not sum two variances and use the sum of their degrees of freedom as the degrees of freedom for your test statistic?